# how to detect the div height dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my previous post.
I had something like

[How to scroll a div in my case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572254/how-to-scroll-a-div-in-my-case)

`RustyToms` Solution works but I have another issue. It seems like when I click `test 16` link. The `items` div can't seem to jump to the top due to the `items` div doesn't have enough height. I am trying to add more height dynamically so `test 16` can jump to the top. so basically I need to detect if the `items` div has enough height to scroll to the top for not only test 16 but other items in my original codes.. I am not sure how to start the process.. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks.

My bad, here is my update jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/BPB7z/9/

Comment: His example works fine for me in Firefox

Comment: 13 gold badges and no code in the question? Wha??

Comment: I'm more thrown off by the lack of paragraphs.

Comment: Good Mr. @FlyingCat, your fiddle appears to work perfectly fine.  Can you try to be more clear with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's last child selector to check if the clicked on DIV is the last DIV in the list.

Use the following animate method implementation:

```
$('#items').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#'+id+'-test').offset().top + $('#items').scrollTop()
           }, 700);  
    if($("#" + id + "-test").is(":last-child")){
        $("#" + id + "-test").css({height: "1000"});
    }
})
```

The above will change the height for "link16-test" to 1000px when its associated anchor is clicked.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPB7z/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Grab current div height:

`var height = $("#div").height();`

Grab current window height:

`var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;`

Answer (score -1):

You can get (and set) the height with .height() method. But your problem is that you don't have anything after the last 'link' div, and it is shorter than #items, so it never can reach the top. Here, it's far more easy to see than to explain:

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SW4UC/)

I added an additional element that fills the remaining space.

```
$('#extraSpace').height($('#items').height() - $('#items div:last').height());
```